# Merge two character columns from two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, character, left-join, dplyr

Would anyone know how to join two character column coming from two similar data frames?

I have a data frame which has already part of the character column filled out and would like to add in the remaining empty rows with characters form an other data frame.

My first data frame looks like this:

```
   > df1 %>% View () 
Source: local data frame [6,249 x 4]

   tripnr shootlat shootlong  area
    (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl) (chr)
1  199801 50.50000 0.5000000      
2  199801 50.48333 0.4166667      
3  199801 50.45000 0.3500000      
4  199801 50.45000 0.3833333      
5  199801 50.41667 0.3166667      
6  199801 50.46667 0.5000000      
7  199801 50.26667 0.3333333      
8  199801 50.28333 0.2333333      
9  199801 50.35000 0.4500000      
10 199801 50.48333 0.4666667
```

The last bit of the area column has got area names.

My second data frame is the opposite (it has area names filled out where df1 doesn't):

```
> df2 %>% View () 
Source: local data frame [6,249 x 4]

   tripnr shootlat shootlong  area
    (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl) (chr)
1  199801 50.50000 0.5000000  VIId
2  199801 50.48333 0.4166667  VIId
3  199801 50.45000 0.3500000  VIId
4  199801 50.45000 0.3833333  VIId
5  199801 50.41667 0.3166667  VIId
6  199801 50.46667 0.5000000  VIId
7  199801 50.26667 0.3333333  VIId
8  199801 50.28333 0.2333333  VIId
9  199801 50.35000 0.4500000  VIId
10 199801 50.48333 0.4666667  VIId
```

What I want to do is combine the two data frames and have the complete area list. 
I tried left_join but this does not combine the two area columns:

```
`> df1 %>% 
+   left_join(df2, by=c( "tripnr", "shootlat", "shootlong"))
Source: local data frame [7,017 x 5]

   tripnr shootlat shootlong area.x area.y
    (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)  (chr)  (chr)
1  199801 50.50000 0.5000000          VIId
2  199801 50.48333 0.4166667          VIId
3  199801 50.45000 0.3500000          VIId
4  199801 50.45000 0.3833333          VIId
5  199801 50.41667 0.3166667          VIId
6  199801 50.46667 0.5000000          VIId
7  199801 50.26667 0.3333333          VIId
8  199801 50.28333 0.2333333          VIId
9  199801 50.35000 0.4500000          VIId
10 199801 50.48333 0.4666667          VIId`
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2, all = T)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not get the result I was hoping for. I tried as well the tidyr unite but then this also unites the NA values..

Comment: can you share the data sets? Also if the columns of tripnr or shootlat or shootlong are supposed to be the same for each row of the merged data set, you could try an inner join using sql